# insertBefore - if element doesnt exists

Tags: jquery

if the index is larger than the actual number of rows nothing is i appended?

```
var elm = $('tr', tbl).eq(index);
if(elm){
    row.insertBefore(elm);
}
else{
    row.appendTo(tbl);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($('tr', tbl).length > index){
    row.insertBefore($('tr', tbl).eq(index));
}
else{
    row.appendTo(tbl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a reference to the `table`, I'd use its native `.rows` property to get the DOM element of the row at your `index`.

Then the simple `if( elm )` statement will work.

```
var elm = tbl[0].rows[index];
if( elm ) {
    row.insertBefore(elm);
}
else{
    row.appendTo(tbl);
}
```

Requires less code, and will run a little faster.